# Using xl6009 on a 5v powerbank circuut

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, boost, speakers, buck-boost

I want to use  xl6009 boost converter on a 5v 2 amp powerbank circuit to power up my 12v amplifire amplifier load is 750ma. What you guy's think about this. Please answer my question ASAP. (sorry for my english)

Comment: 5V @ 2A = 10W. 12V @ 750mA = 9W. So as long as your "xl6009" is at least 90% efficient it'll probably work.

Comment: [Here's one](https://www.electronics-lab.com/project/5v-to-12v-step-up-dc-dc-converter/) but it's only 80% efficient so you'd need a 3A supply.

Answer (score 0):

5V is right at the low end of guaranteed operation for the [XL6009](https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300). Your source is 5V *nominal*, which is not good. My guess is that will *probably* work, with a 2A rated short USB cable in an office environment, but it might well not work at all.

It's mostly characterized for the specialized (but high-volume) application of turning a vehicle electrical system 12-14V input into 18.5V for laptop computers.